Do Mk 9:40 and Mtt 12:30 communicate the same truth?
We read in Mk 9:38-40(NIV).

Teacher,” said John, “we saw someone driving out demons in your name and we told him to stop, because he was not one of us.” “Do not stop him,” Jesus said. “For no one who does a miracle in my name can in the next moment say anything bad about me, for whoever is not against us is for us.

But we read in Mtt 12:29-30 in the context of the Pharisees' allegation on Jesus' source of power to drive out demons:

Or  else how can one enter into a strong man's house, and spoil his goods, except he first bind the strong man? and then he will spoil his house. He that is not with me is against me; and he that gathereth not with me scattereth abroad.

Curiously enough, both sayings of Jesus are in the context of driving out of demons. But do they communicate one and the same thing in so far as a neutral approach to joining Jesus in his redemptive mission is concerned?

Jesus' parables and teachings rarely had a single point - most taught several things with a single story.  The two references/incidents quoted by the OP are a perfect example of this.
Mark 9:33-41
This incident concerns Jesus' comments and rebuke of the disciples concerning their debate about who was the greatest.  (See also Matt 18:6-9, Luke 17:1-4)  Jesus used this opportunity to teach the following:

humility in the kingdom of heaven, “If anyone wants to be first, he must be the last of all and the servant of all.” (V35)
vicarious kindness in the kingdom of heaven, “Whoever welcomes one of these little children in My name welcomes Me, and whoever welcomes Me welcomes not only Me, but the One who sent Me.” (V37)
inclusiveness and shunning the disciples' exclusiveness; all people across all clubs and associations can be part of the kingdom of heaven (V39)
indivisible loyalty - one cannot do a kind act and then speak evil of Jesus (V39); or, one cannot be both for and against Jesus (V40)
heavenly rewards - kindness, even when not recognized in this life will be rewarded in heavenly rewards (V41)

Matt 12:22-30
This passage records Jesus' teaching concerning a demon-possessed man who was blind and mute. (Compare Mark 3:20-27, Luke 11:14-23)  In this passage, Jesus teaches a number of things:

Jesus' miracles were NOT by the power of the Beelzebul, the prince of demons because this would be counterproductive of the Devil to do such things (V25-27)
Jesus' miracles were evidence that the kingdom of heaven had arrived in the person of Jesus and His followers (V28)
The same is true - people cannot fight battles on two fronts; one must deal with enemies in order to make progress (V29)
undivided loyalties - one cannot be both for Satan and for Jesus (V30)

It is immediately obvious that some of the points of each overlap with each other, but others do not.
